# Detect meta (special) keys (Ctrl, Shift, Alt, Tab, Esc, Backspace) from Shell Input

Tags: linux, shell, input, meta

I want to know if anybody knows how to detect meta (special) keys 
 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>) from Shell Input.

I've seen posts that explain how to detect arrow keys and such, but not the above special keys.
Is there any way I can do `$ showkey -s` and use the raw scan-code to somehow get the key input?

Any kind of help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: what do you mean by "Shell Input" ?

Comment: `Tab` and `Backspace` generate keycodes. `Ctrl`, `Shift`, `Alt` and possibly `Esc` modify the keycode that other keys send, but you cannot usually detect them in isolation.

Comment: By shell input I meant reading input from Bash Shell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431836/how-is-esc-alt-ctrl-and-arrow-keys-encoded-in-ssh-shell

Answer (score 3):

In general, you cannot do it. That said:

- X11 sends `KeyPress` and `KeyRelease` events.
- The Linux console provides a set of ioctls that allow low-level access to the keyboard, documented at `console_ioctl(4)`. You would set the keyboard to RAW or MEDIUMRAW mode (**don't confuse these modes with termios' raw mode, they are not related at all**).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it always make sense. The `tty` discipline is doing something (details are gory). Perhaps you need a helper program (e.g. in C, which would use a library like `ncurses` or `readline`) such as [`dialog`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog)!