# Access Keystrokes in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, keyboard

I am trying to access keystrokes in C. I can access alphanumeric keys. How can I access <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> key? 

Plus I read somewhere that sometimes while entering text in console, OS masks backspace key. I would like to know where user pressed backspace key. It's not same as knowing when '\n' was pressed.
GNU C. Ubuntu 11.

Comment: Use the ncurses library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect meta (special) keys (Ctrl, Shift, Alt, Tab, Esc, Backspace) from Shell Input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242404/detect-meta-special-keys-ctrl-shift-alt-tab-esc-backspace-from-shell-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dietrich Epp answered in a comment: use **ncurses** library.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242404/detect-meta-special-keys-ctrl-shift-alt-tab-esc-backspace-from-shell-in/8244551#8244551)

And you might make an [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) client graphical application; in that case use a graphical toolkit library like [GTK](http://gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/)

If you want to make a console application, use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/) or perhaps [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)

And your question, when taken literally, has no sense: the strict C standard don't know what a key or a keystroke is (the only I/O operations mentioned in the standard are related to  `<stdio.h>` thru `FILE`). This is why most people uses additional libraries and standards (in addition of those required by ISO C), eg. [Posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)...

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "you can't", at least not easily or without downloading third party libraries.

Most C programs shouldn't have to know anything about the keyboard or the screen. Standard C is only concerned with reading from and writing to files (the keyboard and screen being special-case files).

Assuming you have a good reason for wanting to access the keyboard directly, you should be looking at the ncurses library (http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html). Ncurses knows how many different (virtual) terminals and keyboards work, and it presents a uniform interface to them. It lets you paint the screen and create a substitute graphical interface using only blocks of text.

Since you use Ubuntu, try running the "aptitude" command to see a good example of what ncurses can do.