# Setting up Tmux prefix to be a key sequence instead of the default key combination

Tags: command-line, terminal, tmux

By default the prefix with which one switches focus to Tmux for command entry is `C-b` (`ctrl + b`). This is a key combination. I would like to, instead, use a key sequence. I would like to doublepress the `control` key (`C C` (`ctrl ctrl`)).

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you cannot do this: terminals use <kbd>Control</kbd> as a *[modifier](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/your-pc-keyboards-modifier-keys.html)* (something done in combination with other key(s).  Repeating a modifier has no effect.

There are several aspects to this:

- [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) (like [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)) runs in a conventional terminal.  The fact that `tmux` is a curses application while `screen` is a termcap application makes no difference, since both are for the same type of terminal.
- the terminals are *conventional* in the sense that they are either hardware terminals such as a DEC `VT100`, or emulate (act like) a hardware terminal.
- all of these ("real" terminals and terminal emulators) are designed to send characters, such as US-ASCII (essentially the POSIX character set, along with control characters).
- to be able to send these characters, some keys were assigned the role of *modifiers*. That is, they are used only in combination with other keys to *modify* the value sent.
- examples of *modifier* keys include: <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>NumLock</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
- while there are graphical applications (such as the [`xev`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_keyboard_keys) X Window application) that can read separate key-press and key-release events for almost any key on a keyboard, terminal emulators use a keyboard configuration which combines these, along with modifier keys. Applications running in the terminal emulator see only the effects of key-presses, modified to reflect which shift-, control-, etc., modifier key you are using.
- a *few* special cases exist, such as the Linux console for which an application can make system calls to get some of the event information.  However, applications (back to `tmux` and `screen`) which are written for conventional terminals do not use these special cases.  That is because the specialized information would be only available on *certain* terminals, while the applications are designed to be able to *attach* (and run seamlessly) on any (conventional) terminal).

Regarding the special function calls, that has been asked before, e.g.,

- [Access Keystrokes in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276394/access-keystrokes-in-c)
- [How to fetch data in a background process in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744064/how-to-fetch-data-in-a-background-process-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Can you help me to understand why this *is* something I can do with, say, Alfred Launcher - set it's hotkey/activation key to double press of `ctrl` - but *not* with something like Tmux in Terminal? What's the difference? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: What about a sequence like `Ctrl-Space t`?