# How can I clear what scanf read?

Tags: c, linux, stdin, signals

I want to be able to clear the value of what scanf read in. In other words, I want to delete the value that was read in by scanf.

Here is my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include <sys/time.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t gotsignal;


void handler(){

gotsignal = 1;

}

int main(){

struct sigaction sig;

sig.sa_handler = handler; 
sig.sa_flags = 0; 
sigemptyset(&sig.sa_mask); 

alarm(5);
sigaction(SIGALRM, &sig, NULL);


int value;

while(!gotsignal){
    printf("Insert a value: \n");
    scanf("%d", &value);
}
}
```

Output:

```
Insert a value: 
5(dont press enter)[JPS@localhost c]$ 5 <-
```

Is it possible(if yes how) to clear the 5?

I have been reading about terminal settings, fflushs, stdin, but i couldn't figure it out. Any help please?

EDIT: After a lot of trys i think i found something that works. If anyone has this problem this worked for me(not sure if it works on other systems and stuff, kinda new to this):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h> 
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>


volatile sig_atomic_t gotsignal;


void handler()
{

gotsignal = 1;

}


int main(){

struct sigaction sig;

sig.sa_handler = handler; 
sig.sa_flags = 0; 
sigemptyset(&sig.sa_mask); 

alarm(5);
sigaction(SIGALRM, &sig, NULL);


int value;
while(!gotsignal){
    printf("Insert a value: \n");
    scanf("%d", &value);
}
printf("\n");
tcflush(STDOUT_FILENO,TCIOFLUSH); <-important bit!

return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Insert a value: 
5
Insert a value: 
5(no enter was pressed)!
[JPS@localhost c]$ <- NO MORE NR 5! :D
```

Comment: Good question. I am deleting my answer, as useless. Trying `system("stty raw");` also doesn't work.  Perhaps shell-dependent?

Comment: In this case `scanf()` _didn't_ read the value, because you never sent the line to the process (check the return value and `errno` - you'll see it was interrupted by the signal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library. But I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "clear the 5".

The simplest example might be

```
// file testrl.c
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () 
{
   char bufprompt[20];
   char* lin = NULL;
   int cnt = 0;
   for (;;) {
     memset(bufprompt, 0, sizeof(bufprompt));
     cnt++;
     snprintf(bufprompt, sizeof(bufprompt)-1, "%d: ", cnt);
     lin = readline(bufprompt);
     if (!lin) 
       break;
     printf("you typed %s\n", lin);
     free (lin);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Compile the above with `gcc -Wall -g testrl.c -o testrl -lreadline`

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242404/detect-meta-special-keys-ctrl-shift-alt-tab-esc-backspace-from-shell-in/8244551#8244551)

Comment: What i mean by clear the 5 is after the program is finished running, since he got the signal, i don't want to read the 5 and i don't want the 5 in the terminal, as he stays there, even after the program is finished.

Comment: The point is that TTY & pseudo-terminals are complex beasts on Linux, and (to summarize & simplify) part of the line buffering is done by the kernel. You really should use a library like `readline` or `ncurses` as I told you in other answers. `scanf` is not enough for you if you want to "clear the 5".

Comment: I read about the readline but i didn't understand. What do i need to import? Could you give me a simple example?

Comment: I gave an example, but I did not bother testing it. It might not work!

Comment: I get this: fatal error: readline.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated. Do i need to install it on my machine or?

Comment: You need to install the readline development package, ie `libreadline-dev` on Debian or Ubuntu

Comment: Btw, is there any (easy) way to tell the terminal to just delete a character, like a user doing a backspace? Maybe that would fix it?

Answer (score 4):

See these links for good answers:

- [How can I flush pending input so that a user's typeahead isn't read at the next prompt? Will fflush(stdin) work?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html)
- [If fflush won't work, what can I use to flush input?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html)

To quote the most interesting:

> There is **no standard way** to discard unread characters from a stdio
>   input stream. Some vendors do implement fflush so that fflush(stdin)
>   discards unread characters, although portable programs cannot depend
>   on this. (Some versions of the stdio library implement **fpurge** or
>   **fabort** calls which do the same thing, but these aren't standard,
>   either.) Note, too, that flushing stdio input buffers is not
>   necessarily sufficient: unread characters can also accumulate in
>   other, OS-level input buffers. If you're trying to actively discard
>   input (perhaps in anticipation of issuing an unexpected prompt to
>   confirm a destructive action, for which an accidentally-typed ``y''
>   could be disastrous), **you'll have to use a system-specific technique**
>   to detect the presence of typed-ahead input; see questions [19.1](http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html) and
>   [19.2](http://c-faq.com/osdep/readavail.html). Keep in mind that users can become frustrated if you discard input that happened to be typed too quickly.

Comment: So, there is no way around this? With system specific you mean i could try to look for a solution for fedora, but then in ubuntu wouldn't work?

Comment: No with system specific they mean that, for example, it might work on Linux, but not on Windows or OS X. Try fpurge, should work for any linux.

Comment: No, most recent Linux distributions would work likewise. But probably, it won't work the same on MacOSX or FreeBSD